# Howto save content with the markdown editor editor.md?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, editor, editor.md

I would like to use [editor.md](https://pandao.github.io/editor.md/en.html) to edit markdown code.

The features of editor.md are good and the editor is really easy to use.
I run into the problem to save my edited content. I can click the close editor button but then the content is gone.

**What is the supposed way to save the editor content?**

Is it even possible to export the content as html or pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The editor content gets written back to the former textarea element and can be fetched from there.